# How to create an allure report in multi module project

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, allure

I am able to create allure report for my automation tests at individual module level and works fine locally but that doesn't seem to work on Jenkins where all modules are run as part of pipeline and i guess jenkins is unable to find an aggregated allure report at project directory level. Is there a way to handle/solve this? Any suggestions appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtUex.png)

On Jenkins an empty report is attached and log reads -
$ /opt/fsroot/tools/ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.tools.AllureCommandlineInstallation/2.13.1/bin/allure generate -c -o /opt/fsroot/workspace/Flow/~*/*-*-tests/allure-report
allure-results does not exists
Report successfully generated to /opt/fsroot/workspace/Flow/~*/*-*-tests/allure-report
Allure report was successfully generated.

Comment: can you please let us know if its fixed

Answer (score 0):

prerequisite : [allure plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/allure-jenkins-plugin/) is installed in Jenkins

After test stage use below in post stage

```
post {
  always {
    allure includeProperties: false, jdk: '', results: [[path: 'target/allure-results']]
    }
  }
```

Comment: If this answer resolved your problem, then please consider accepting it, by clicking the green checkmark to the left of this answer.

Comment: This was already done. Allure reports are added in post stage. Even then issue is not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can always manually copy results from your modules to the project's root if the core plugin functionality doesn't work for you for some reason. Here's a Gradle example. But you can do the same for the Maven project as well.

```
tasks.register<Copy>("copyApiResults") {
    from("${projectDir}/api/build/allure-results")
    into("${buildDir}/allure-results")
}

tasks.register<Copy>("copyUiResults") {
    from("${projectDir}/ui/build/allure-results")
    into("${buildDir}/allure-results")
}
```